# How to trigger callbacks after angular js directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular JS and I'm trying to figure out how to do things AFTER a directive completes.

For example, there is a directive: [ng-mousemove](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angMousemove). If I want something to change color when the mouse moves, add `ng-mousemove="mouseMoveFunc()"` and change the relevant css properties in the controller. But what about changing it back? (There's no ng-mousemoveStop directive)

I've run into this a couple times, so I think I'm missing something about how it's supposed to work.

Comment: sounds likely better to create own directive so you can `unbind` also

Answer (score 0):

in the controller you can do something like this:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    Move the mouse on blue box. If you stop to move or leave the box, the
    color comes back to original color.
    <div ng-controller="mycontroller" 
        style="height:200px" 
        ng-style="mystyle()" 
        ng-mousemove="mouseMoveFunc()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("mycontroller",["$scope","$timeout",function($scope, $timeout){
     $scope.mystyle = function(){
         if(queue<1){
             return {"background":"blue"};
         }else{
             return {"background":"black"};
         }
     };
     var queue=0;
     $scope.mouseMoveFunc = function(){
         queue++;
         $timeout(function(){
             queue--;
         },100);
     }
 }]);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9sTg/10/)